# What is the correct way to use "as" to explain a reasons in English sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

### Problem:

Assume that I have a reason and I would like to express it in my sentence using the word `as`. What is the correct way to construct my sentence?

### Example:

**As the main idea of this section is in introducing a new estimation method, then, the work is limited to a simulation study**.

Is this a good way to use `As`? Is my sentence correct?

Any help, please?

Comment: Okay, so to tidy this up: "As the main idea of this section is to introduce a new estimation method, the work is limited to a simulation study."

Comment: Any reason not to use "since" in place of "as"? Flows better in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you've used "as" here is correct, and a common phrasing used in academic writing and similar documents. However, the "then" in the middle of the sentence sounds awkward to me. As [ralph.m](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/86230/) notes in the comments, a cleaner way to phrase it would be

> As the main idea of this section is to introduce a new estimation method, the work is limited to a simulation study.